# How to get records from SQL Server for every hour only first record in a day in a month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code like this below, I want to generate records for last 30 days from SQL Server for every hour first record in a day. for every minute there are like 10 records. I want to grab only one record for every hour. I want only 24 records for each day

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ordertime >= '2019-07-21 12:00' AND ordertime <= '2019-08-21 12:00' ;
```

Comment: "for every hour first record in a day".  No idea what you mean.  Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Comment: for every minute there are like 10 records. I want to grab only one record for every hour. I want only 24 records for each day.

Comment: probably include that description in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Row_Number

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT *,rn = row_number() over (partition by datepart(hour,getdate()) order by [key])

 FROM table WHERE 
ordertime >='2019-07-21 12:00' AND ordertime <= '2019-08-21 12:00> ;
)
select *
from cte where rn =1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first record for each hour using `row_number()`.  The correct expression is:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, ordertime), DATEPART(HOUR, ordertime)
                                ORDER BY ordertime
                               ) seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE ordertime >= '2019-07-21 12:00' AND
      ordertime < '2019-08-21 12:00' AND
      seqnum = 1;
```

Note that the `PARTITION BY` clause has both the full date and hour.  This uniquely identifies each hour.  `ROW_NUMBER()` itself is enumerating the rows, based on the `ORDER BY`.  So, "1" is for the first record.

I also changed your second comparison to `<` rather than `<=`.  That makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select * from (
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY datepart(hour, ordertime ),datepart(day,ordertime ) ORDER BY ordertime 
           ) rn from table 
) a 
WHERE rn=1 and ordertime >='2019-07-21 12:00' AND ordertime <= '2019-08-21 12:00> ;
```

This uses the ROW_NUMBER function, this gives each row a number in regard of a partition specified ,in this case the partition was made for day and hour, this would mean records in the same day and hour will be assigned row numbers. In the outer query Im returning the records that get assigned the row number 1, which means that only one record will be returned for each hour of each day.

Bear in mind that you can add another field in the ORDER BY part of the partition to specifiy what record is the record you return (for example if you want the last record of each hour you would ORDER BY ordertime DESC)